# The healing of Aloe plant

Tags: plant-health

Our daughter has stabbed the aloe plant about three different times on each stem with a pen.. will it heal itself ? I don’t know how she got the time or what she was thinking but each stem has little holes in it & I need to know if there is something I can do to save it or not

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if left alone they will heal.  You will always be able to see the scar, but they will heal.  Just like a cut in a human it takes a little time, but not that long. Make sure you keep them clean and avoid getting any water near the damaged parts.   Also like a human, a cut can later lead to a infection, but that is unlikely.